# Validation for adding atleat three skills in input box using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Need to add validation  for adding atleast three skills in textbox.
I am having a form for applying a job in that there is an option for entering the primary skills which the user knows and those are separated by comma.So i need to add validation for that if the user enters only one skill while submiting the form it should show the message as atleaset three skills are required. I am using codeigniter php

```
<div class="primaryskillss">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control primaryskills" name="primary_skills"  value="<?php echo set_value('primary_skills');?>" placeholder="Primary Skills(Enter any 3 Skills separated by comma)" required>
                      <?php echo form_error('primary_skills', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>  
                    </div>  
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success successss" id="submits">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can we get some code?

Comment: You want user to enter 3 skills in textbox?
Why don't you use text area or better select boxes?

Comment: @Nitesh yes i need to enter three skills in text box that will be added by user.It is not a dropdown

Comment: @Salketer i am asking for idea how to do that

Comment: OK, if you want to add 3 skills in textbox only, you can separate skills by comma and validate on blur if there are at least 3 values after splitting by comma.

Comment: "asking for ideas" is not in the scope of stack overflow, that's why I asked...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(substr_count($_POST['primary_skills'],',')<2){
    //Error
}
```

If you are forcing the user to sepperate the skills with commas, simply count the number of commas there are? It's the poor man's way but it should work...

To prevent users from putting just ",,", we should try to fetch using a regex to test that the commas are separating at least one character:

```
if(preg_match(/.+,.+,.+/,$_POST['primary_skills'])){
    //Error
}
```

Comment: Note that you could go way fancier on the regex if you wanted... Like counting only real word characters.

Comment: Not getting you

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but I can't do better without a better question.